# Windows 7 Dual Monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I just purchased 2 new `Dell E2414H` monitors and installed Windows 7 on my recent computer build and one monitor is plugged into VGA the other to DVI.
I have run Ubuntu on this computer from a disk already and the screens work fine in extended mode but in Windows:

- If both are plugged in before booting, my display is duplicated
- If only one is plugged in before booting, The other monitor won't work

When I go to my screen resolution settings it only ever recognizes 1 monitor. **Does anyone know how to get Windows 7 to recognize both monitors?**

*Additional Info:* I am using integrated graphics (Intel Core i5-4690K) and I have also installed the Dell drivers from the disk and have tried detecting hardware updates in the device manager. Thanks in advance.

Comment: most interesting part is your graphic card, is a built-in or external? If the graphic card has two DVI better use these ports because they help the PC recognize the monitors as external device with driver, vga doesn't

Comment: I'm using integrated graphics and both my [motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130780&cm_re=intel_motherboard-_-13-130-780-_-Product) and CPU specify that they support dual and even triple screens.

Comment: Ok, I saw the motherboard, you have to go with the Intel HD Graphics and make the configuration from there, and remove the configuration from windows settings. if you are not using the latest driver or only the driver that get from windows update you can download the driver from Intel

Comment: I have tried settting the multiple monitor mode in BIOS but it didn't do anything. Do you know, if it is a CPU issue why did dual monitors work in Ubuntu?

Comment: +1 to emirjonb for a working answer. I used Intel's driver update utility and it updated the integrated graphics and after a restart everything worked as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to change to extend mode.

Comment: This does not work. In fact it does not do anything. If it would recognize that multiple displays were connected then it should work but windows only recognizes that one display is connected

Comment: @j_v_wow_d then the problem is with your graphics driver. Win+P always switch between the 4 screen modes since windows Vista and up. Another solution is right click on desktop > resolution > extend

Comment: Would you mind to post a screenshot of right click on desktop -> Screen Resolution?